# Calculate and Display the Percentage of Time Passed

Tags: java

I'm going through ThinkJava Version 6.1.0 (latest) and in Chapter 2 Exercise 2.3, I'm stuck on #5 which asks "Calculate and display the percentage of the day that has passed. You might run into problems when computing percentages with integers, so consider using floating-point."

I've attempted to get the percentage, but I'm not getting the right result.

I've completed the first 4 questions. Here is what I have so far:

```
public class Date {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int hour = 13, minute = 58, second = 45;
        double percentage;
        double secondsSinceMidnight = second + (minute * 60) + (hour * 3600);
        double secondsRemainingInDay = (60-second) + ((60-1-minute)*60) + (24-1-hour)*3600;

        percentage = (secondsSinceMidnight * 100) / 60;

        System.out.println("Number of seconds since midnight:");
        System.out.println(secondsSinceMidnight);

        System.out.println("Number of seconds remaining in the day:");
        System.out.println(secondsRemainingInDay);

        System.out.println("Percentage of the day past:");
        System.out.println(percentage + "%");
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help and support!

Comment: try to use floating point instead for any double, add .00 after it. I.e. 60 -> 60.00; 1 -> 1.00.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the formula for calculating the percentage of the day already past.

```
    percentage = (secondsSinceMidnight * 100) / 60;
```

Does not seem right to me. It should be something like

```
    percentage =  100 * secondsSinceMidnight  / totalSecondsInDay;
```

`totalSecondsInDay` can be the sum of `secondsRemainingInDay` and `secondsSinceMidnight`

Comment: Thank you so much @Stefan ! This totally helped me out. For some reason I just couldn't wrap my head around the calculating the percentage.

Answer (score 0):

i think your code have problems with type-casting

in line 3 exchange int with double:

```
double hour = 13, minute = 58, second = 45;
```

or there is problem with constant numbers , write numbers in this way : 60.0 instead of 60

Comment: I changed all my variables to double, and using @Stefan answer, it totally worked and I was able to solve my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example with a hardcoded time. It's in military time obviously so keep that in mind.

```
public class Time 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int startHour = 12;         //when you start editing program
        int startMinute = 00;
        int startSecond = 00;
        System.out.print("Number of seconds since midnight: ");
        startMinute = (startHour * 60 + startMinute );
        startSecond = (startMinute * 60 + startSecond);
        System.out.print(startSecond);
        System.out.println(" seconds");

        int secondInADay = 86400;    //number of seconds in a day   
        System.out.print ("Seconds remaining in the day: ");
        System.out.println (secondInADay - startSecond);

        System.out.print("Percent of the day that has passed: ");
        double startSeconds = 43200;    //number of seconds that have passed in a day at start of editing program
        System.out.println(startSeconds * 100 / 86400);

        int endHour = 16;               //time when finished editing program
        int endMinute = 00;
        int endSecond = 00;

        System.out.print ("Difference = ");     //difference in time from start to finish
        endMinute = (endHour * 60 + endMinute );
        endSecond = (endMinute * 60 + endSecond);
        System.out.print (endSecond - startSecond);
        System.out.print (" seconds");
    }
}
```